Euler's gamma function and Riemann zeta
On page 7 Edwards gives Euler’s factorial function:
$\displaystyle n! = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} x^n dx$
for $n=1,2,3,\ldots $
On the next page he gives the same in Gauss’ notation
$\displaystyle \Pi(s) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} x^s dx$
for $s>-1$
Then on page 9, he writes:

Substituting $nx$ for $x$ in Euler’s integral for $\Pi(s-1)$ gives

$\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} e^{-nx} x^{s-1} dx = \frac{\Pi(s-1)}{n^s}$
for $s>0$ and $n=1,2,3,\ldots$
How did we get the $n^s$ in the denominator by substituting $nx$ for $x$?

Hint: $$
\Pi(s-1)=\int_0^\infty  {{\rm e}^{ - x} x^{s - 1} {\rm d}x}  = \int_0^\infty  {{\rm e}^{ - nx} (nx)^{s - 1} {\rm d}(nx)}  = n^s \int_0^\infty  {{\rm e}^{ - nx} x^{s - 1} {\rm d}x}
$$

@Gary Got it! Thanks. So I missed replacing the $x$ with $nx$. I replaced only the exponent.

It is a change of integration variables from $x$ to $t$ via $x=nt$. Later you can call the $t$ as $x$ again.

@Gary I'm sorry, I'm sure this is trivial but I could not figure out how you factored out $n^s$ from $(nx)^{s-1}$ and $d(nx)$

$(nx)^{s-1}=n^{s-1} x^{s-1}$ and ${\rm d}(nx) = \frac{{{\rm d}(nx)}}{{{\rm d}x}}{\rm d}x = (nx)'{\rm d}x = n{\rm d}x$.

@Gary Maybe you are assuming too much about my level of calculus:) What does the prime notation mean here $(nx)'$. Derivative? You multiply $d(nx)$ by $dx/dx$ and obtain $ndx$. Even so, how do we get $n^s$ from $n^{s-1}$ and $n$?

Yes, prime is derivative with respect to $x$. High school maths: $ n^{s-1}\cdot n=n^{s-1+1}=n^s$. Before reading a textbook on the Riemann zeta function, you should get familiar with real and complex analysis (and basic high school algebra).

@Gary Thanks. I guess you're right.

@Gary By coincidence I came across this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.08062 On p.77 he makes the same substitution $x\rightarrow nx$ but he does not make the substitution $dx \rightarrow d(nx)$ so he factors out $n^{s-1}$ not $n^s$. Do you have any comment on this? What is the convention for manipulating $dx$?

My comment is that the author of that arxiv preprint doesn't know basic calculus. This is why one should use a different symbol for the new variable, i.e., replace $x$ with $n\cdot t$, then the mistake becomes more apparent. Here, $t$ will also vary along the positive real line.

@Gary I found the topic interesting so I asked a new question instead of continuing here in comments https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4915092/change-of-variable-in-gamma-function
