Change of variable in gamma function
This is a continuation of my question here
This one is about calculus and change of variables. Instead of continuing the discussion in comments I decided to ask a new question.
Before the change of variables we have this expression for Gamma:
$$\Pi(s-1) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} x^{s-1} dx$$
For $s=5$ this integral evaluates to $4!=24$
After the change of variables we have
$$ \Pi(s-1) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-nx} (nx)^{s-1} d(nx)$$
for $s>0$ and $n=1,2,3,\ldots$
For $n=1$ we have the original integral.
For $n=2$ and $s=5$ we have
$$\Pi(5-1) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-2x} (2x)^{5-1} d(2x)$$
But, WolframAlpha cannot evaluate this integral. Is this even a meaningful integral?
What confuses me is that we equate both integrals to gamma:
$$\Pi(s-1) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} x^{s-1} d(x) =  \int_0^{\infty} e^{-nx} (2x)^{s-1} d(nx)$$
But the integral with change of variables cannot be evaluated.
What am I missing?

WolframAlpha cannot evaluate $\int_0^\infty e^{-2x}x^{5-1}d(2x)$ because of $d(2x)$, which is interpreted as a syntax error. Replace it with $2dx$

@AnneBauval Thanks. With $2dx$ it works and gives 1.5. How does this related to the factorial of 5?

@AnneBauval As per your first comment, it looks like I dropped "2x". I fixed it now.

@AnneBauval Not directly related to the question but I'm curious why we are working with $(s-1)$ instead of $s$? Euler’s gamma function $\displaystyle \Pi(s) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} x^s dx$ is valid for $s>-1$ so it already covers the situation for $s>1$

Euler's gamma function is $\Gamma(s)=\Pi(s-1)$. The $\Pi$ notation is not really used in modern mathematics. Nevertheless, working with $s-1$ will lead to $\zeta(s)$ instead of $\zeta(s+1)$.

$\Gamma(s)= \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} x^{s-1}dx$$=\Pi(s-1)$. The advantage (?) of $\Pi$ is that $n!=\Pi(n)$.
